# jQuery change text after a certain amount of time

Tags: jquery

I have a C# MVC application that presents the user with a login page.  When the user clicks the submit button, I execute a jQuery to show a previously hidden `<div>` with a spinning circle and the text that says `Please wait while we log you in...`.  Then the jQuery submits the form to a controller of my application where the login process starts.

The login process involves accumulating a lot of data across multiple databases so it can take up to 10-15 seconds, depending on the device used to log in.

Is there a way to have the text that is displayed change from `Please wait while we log you in...` to something like `Sorry for the delay but we are working on it...` after 10 seconds?  This way, the text changes so the user doesnt think they are hung up.

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a bad system if you're having to wait 15 seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) to update the text after 10 seconds :

```js
function login() {
  $("#wait-message").show();
  setTimeout(() => $("#wait-message").text("Sorry for the delay but we are working on it..."), 10000);
}
```

```css
#wait-message {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="login()">log in</button>
<div id="wait-message">Please wait while we log you in...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `setInterval` we can produce something

You can change time from 1s to 10s

```js
$(function(){

  var text = setInterval(function(){
      var r = (Math.random() + 1).toString(36).substring(7);
      $('.text').text(r);
  },1000);// 1sec

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">1234</div>
```